# NSArray displays next element with buttonPressed method

Tags: nsarray

I have an array of strings and I want to access the next element in that array every time I press a button in my app, I don't want to have a duplicate string pop up, so I want to go through the whole array, and then start over after I reach the end of the array... so each button press will show the next element in the array..my buttonPressed method is in the viewDidLoad method.
ty

Comment: What does your `buttonPressed` method look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
set index = 0

on button press:
show(strings[index])
increment index
if index is equal to strings.length then set index = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going for something like this:

```
@interface ViewController() {
    int index;
}
// ...
end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    index = 0;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    if (index == yourArray.count)
        index = 0;
    NSString *nextItem = [yourArray objectAtIndex:index];
    // Use the string you just got...
    index++;
}

end
```